# Comparing two column, insert shift cell down until it find another match

Tags: excel

I have two rows of large data two compare that look like this [Step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPWVi.png).

What i'm trying to do is, it will insert blank cells until it find another match that look like this [Step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eQzu.png).

Sorry for my bad English, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can achieve this using a loop statement. If cell1 is not equal to cell2, it will insert blank, else it will insert the cell2 value.

Or set a if else statement on your Cell2:

```
IIF(Cell1 <> Cell2, return true, return false)
```

Comment: how can i achieve that? Sorry, i'm not familiar with macro and vba.

Comment: Or set a if else statement on your Cell2, IIF(Cell1 <> Cell2, return true, return false)